# Exception in thread Thread-2: Python Machine Learning Error : list out of range Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, tflearn

I'm trying to make a classifier for my data. But as a newbie in Machine Learning and Python stuff, I keep getting a strange error which I can't figure out. My code is

**CODE**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as cio
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpg
from random import shuffle
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import cv2

a = cio.loadmat("D:/compCarsThesisData/data/misc/make_model_name.mat")

images = "D:/compCarsThesisData/data/image/"
IMG_SIZE = 64
MODEL_NAME = 'Classification'
LR = 1e-3

b = a['make_names']

d = []

for i in range(b.size):
  d.append(b[i][0][0])
  print(d)

labels_dic = {v: k for v, k in enumerate(d)}
print(labels_dic)
indices = np.arange(163)
depth = 163

y = tf.one_hot(indices,depth)

sess = tf.Session()

result = sess.run(y)#,feed_dict=None,options=None, run_metadata=labels_dic)
print(result)
labels = []

labels.append((result,labels_dic))
print(labels)


for root, _, files in os.walk(images):
 cdp = os.path.abspath(root)
 for f in files:
     name,ext = os.path.splitext(f)
     if ext == ".jpg":
       cip = os.path.join(cdp,f)
       ci = mpg.imread(cip)
       image = cv2.cv2.resize(ci,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
       image = np.array(image)
       print(image)


 training_data = []

 training_data.append((image,labels))
 shuffle(training_data)
 np.save('training_data_make_model', training_data)

 testing_data = []
 testing_data.append((image,labels))
 print("TestingDATA",testing_data)

 shuffle(testing_data)

# if the data already created
# training_data = np.load('training_data_make_model.npy')
# testing_data = np.load('training_data_make_model.npy')

train = training_data[:-50000]
test = testing_data[-50000:]

X_train = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

y_train = [i[1] for i in train]

X_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
y_test = [i[1] for i in test]
print("YTEST",y_test)



tf.reset_default_graph()
convnet = input_data(shape=[None,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3],name='input')
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log', tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit({'input': X_train}, {'targets': y_train}, n_epoch=10,
          validation_set=0.1,
          snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

The snapshot of my .mat file is [image: The .mat file contains cell arrays, I'm using ['make_names'] array]

The .mat file contains cell arrays, as for now I'm using ['make_names'] which have names of cars as a labels and converting them into one hot encoded and appending them together with training data as you can see above.

**.mat file**

The appended data with labels and .mat files look like this

**LABELS WITH ONE HOT ENCODE**

```
[[1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]]
[(array([[1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32), {0: 'ABT', 1: 'BAC', 2: 'Conquest', 3: 'DS', 4: 'Dacia', 5: 'Fisker', 6: 'GMC', 7: 'Gumpert', 8: 'Hennessey', 9: 'Icona', 10: 'Jeep', 11: 'KTM', 12: 'MELKUS', 13: 'MG', 14: 'MINI', 15: 'Mazzanti', 16: 'Noble', 17: 'PGO', 18: 'SPIRRA', 19: 'SSC', 20: 'Scion', 21: 'TESLA', 22: 'TVR', 23: 'Tramontana', 24: 'Zenvo', 25: 'smart', 26: 'Yiqi', 27: 'Mitsubishi', 28: 'Shangqidatong', 29: 'Spyker N.V.', 30: 'Dongnan', 31: 'Dongfeng', 32: 'Dongfengxiaokang', 33: 'Dongfengfengdu', 34: 'Dongfengfengshen', 35: 'Dongfengfengxing', 36: 'Zxauto', 37: 'Zhonghua', 38: 'Toyota', 39: 'Zinoro', 40: 'Jiulong', 41: 'Isuzu', 42: 'Wuling', 43: 'AC Chnitzer', 44: 'Zoyte', 45: 'Iveco', 46: 'Bufori', 47: 'Porsche', 48: 'Mitsuoka', 49: 'Chrysler', 50: 'Lamorghini ', 51: 'Kombat', 52: 'Cadillac', 53: 'Buck', 54: 'Lifan', 55: 'Lorinser', 56: 'Rolls-Royce', 57: 'BAW', 58: 'Baihc', 59: 'Beiqiweiwang', 60: 'Beiqihuansu', 61: 'Beiqi New Energy', 62: 'Huapu', 63: 'Huatai', 64: 'Huaqi', 65: 'Carlsson', 66: 'Shuanghuan', 67: 'Shuanglong', 68: 'Geely', 69: 'Venucia', 70: 'Haval', 71: 'Hafei', 72: 'Volkswagen', 73: 'Daihatsu', 74: 'Chrey', 75: 'Besturn', 76: 'Benz', 77: 'Audi', 78: 'Wisemann', 79: 'Wealeak', 80: 'BWM', 81: 'Baojun', 82: 'Bentley', 83: 'Brabus', 84: 'Bugatti', 85: 'Pagani', 86: 'Guangqichuanqi', 87: 'GAC', 88: 'Karry', 89: 'Ciimo', 90: 'CHTC', 91: 'Jaguar', 92: 'Morgan', 93: 'Subaru', 94: 'Skoda', 95: 'Xinkai', 96: 'Nissan', 97: 'Changhe', 98: 'RANZ', 99: 'Honda', 100: 'Lincoln', 101: 'Peugeot', 102: 'Opel', 103: 'Oley', 104: 'BYD', 105: 'Jonway', 106: 'Huizhong', 107: 'Jianghuai', 108: 'Jiangling', 109: 'Vauxhall', 110: 'Volvo', 111: 'Ferrari', 112: 'Haige', 113: 'Haima', 114: 'Haima(Zhengzhou)', 115: 'Cheetah', 116: 'Maserati', 117: 'Hyundai ', 118: 'Everus', 119:
'Ruiqi', 120: 'Fuqiqiteng', 121: 'Ford', 122: 'Futian', 123: 'Fudi', 124: 'Koenigsegg', 125: 'HongQi', 126: 'Luxgen', 127: 'SAAB', 128: 'Denza', 129: 'Yingzhi', 130: 'Infiniti', 131: 'Roewe', 132: 'Lotus', 133: 'FIAT', 134: 'Saab', 135: 'Lancia', 136: 'Seat', 137: 'Qoros', 138: 'Acura', 139: 'KIA', 140: 'Lotus', 141: 'LAND-ROVER', 142: 'McLaren', 143: 'Maybach', 144: 'Dodge', 145: 'Mustang', 146: 'Jinlv', 147: 'Jinbei', 148: 'Suzuki', 149: 'GreatWall', 150: 'Changan Business', 151: 'Changan', 152: 'Alfa Romeo', 153: 'Aston Martin', 154: 'Lufeng', 155: 'Shanqitongjia', 156: 'Chevy', 157: 'Citroen', 158: 'Lexus', 159: 'Renault', 160: 'Shouwang', 161: 'MAZDA', 162: 'Huanghai'})]
```

But every time I try to run this, it gives me an error like.

**ERROR**

```
Run id: Classification
Log directory: log/
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner

    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)                                     1, in fill_batch_ids_queue
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 201, in fill_batch_ids_queue                                                        5, in next_batch_ids
    ids = self.next_batch_ids()
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 215, in next_batch_ids
    batch_start, batch_end = self.batches[self.batch_index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```